# partial fraction expansion of $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$

Tags: partial-fractions, meromorphic-functions

how can you determine the partial fraction expansion of the following meromorphic function :$$f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$$

Is there a general way (or at least ways that work out for most of the common exercises concerning that topic) to determine partial fraction expansions of meromorphic functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$e^{z}-1$ : its zeros are of order $1$ at $2i k \pi$ where its derivative $ = 1$. Let
$$g(z) = \lim_{K \to \infty}\sum_{k=-K}^K \frac{1}{z-2i k \pi}=\frac{1}{z}+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{z-2i k \pi}+\frac{1}{z+2i k \pi})$$
It is meromorphic with poles at $2i \pi k$ of order $1$ and residue $1$

Thus $$\frac{1}{e^{z}-1}-g(z)$$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ (it is entire). 
A little work shows $g(z)$ and hence $\frac{1}{e^{z}-1}-g(z)$ is $1$-periodic and bounded as $z \to \pm i \infty$.
Thus $\frac{1}{e^{z}-1}-g(z)$  is a bounded entire function, and by the Liouville theorem it is constant, ie.
$$\frac{1}{e^{z}-1} = C+\frac{1}{z}+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{z-2i k \pi}+\frac{1}{z+2i k \pi})$$
For finding $C$ you can look at $z=0$ : 
$$C = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}z-\frac{1}{e^z-1} +\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{z-2i k \pi}+\frac{1}{z+2i k \pi})$$
$$ = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}z-\frac{1}{e^z-1} +\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2z}{z^2+4 k^2 \pi^2}=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}z-\frac{1}{e^z-1}  = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: it's only periodic on imaginary axis so how it implies that it is bounded on whole plane? Liouville's theorem that I have studied from Churchil's book supposes boundedness of f on whole plane.

Comment: @Ali reuns is actually making things more complicated than they are. You can just use the residue theorem (what he is doing in secret). See here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844780/show-that-ez-1-z-e-fracz2-prod-n-1-infty-left1-fracz24-n2/4844999#4844999 for a similar calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The function is periodic with period $2\pi i$. Therefore we only have to look at the poles in a strip of width $2\pi i$, and in particular, the one at $z=0$, which is simple and has residue $1$. Therefore
$$ \frac{1}{e^z-1} = f(z) + \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n\neq 0} \frac{1}{z-2\pi i n}+ \frac{1}{2\pi i n}, $$
where $f(z)$ is periodic and analytic. In fact, the latter function is $\frac{1}{2}\coth{\frac{1}{2}z}$ (there are various ways to show this: Fourier series, a certain integral, or the contour integral trick you've probably seen). We can subtract and conclude that $f(z)=1/2$.